# Значение корня "ект"

Tags: словообразование

Кто-нибудь знает значение этого корня?

Присутствует в таких заимствованных словах как "объект", "проект", "субъект". Также в математических понятиях "биекция", "сюръекция", "инъекция". Одним, словом, распространён.

Поиски в викисловарях привели к вероятному происхождению от латыни "iect" с добавлением соответствующих латинских приставок ("об" = "над", "суб" = "под", "про" = "перед" - приблизительные переводы на русский).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно проследить по этимологии слова ОБЪЕКТ (Цыганенко)

ОБЪЕКТ - "предмет, на который направлено действие", "внешний мир";
"дополнение" (в грамматике). Заимствовано в XVI в. из лат., возможно,
через посредство польск. яз. Польск. objekt из лат. objectum "предмет"
из прич. objectus "лежащий (находящийся) впереди" глаг. objicere "бросать
вперед", "держать перед собой", производного с прист. ob- "вперед" (см. о)
от jacere "бросать, метать", "ставить, класть". Следоват., объект - как бы
"противолежащий" (по отношению к субъекту), "внешний", "то, что существует
вне нас" (филос.).

См.  субъект - то, что лежит в основе. В латинском это форма причастия "лежащий внизу, под...", т.е. подлежащее, тот, кто совершает действие, "предмет мысли".

Проект - вперёд + бросать - брошенный вперёд, т.е. "наперёд сделанный набросок", "план на будущее".

Об объекте:  http://lib.co.ua/dict/cyganenkogp/etimologicheskiyslovarrusskogo.jsp

Comment: Благодарю, исчерпывающе. Вот с "субъектом" не совсем очевидная интерпретация, могли бы вы чуть побольше расписать схему образования этого слова?

Comment: суб=под; субъект=лежащий под... Смысл: что-то лежит, а на нём держится всё остальное, т.е. субъект является основой, от него зависит действие. В противоположность объекту, на который направлено действие чего-то. Потом появилось значение субъект=человек.(от него же всё в мире зависит)В философии субъективное мнение -принадлежащее субъекту, отдельному человеку, объективное - лежит перед субъектом, не зависит от человека, субъекта, принадлежит внешнему миру.

Answer (score 0):

Можно прочитать здесь.